# different portscan tools give different results

Tags: network, network-scanners, ports

I have different results as of my open TCP ports. When using `nmap -sS 127.0.0.1`, I get some 5 usual open ports, but when using osx built-in tool as `stroke`, I get those 5 ports plus 5 extra ports. How can it come ?

first `nmap -sS 127.0.0.1`

```
Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-03 12:00 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
88/tcp   open  kerberos-sec
548/tcp  open  afp
631/tcp  open  ipp
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
```

and `./stroke 127.0.0.1 0 6000` gives

```
Open TCP Port:  80          http
     Open TCP Port:     88          kerberos
     Open TCP Port:     548         afpovertcp
     Open TCP Port:     631         ipp
     Open TCP Port:     4370
     Open TCP Port:     4371
     Open TCP Port:     4380
     Open TCP Port:     4381
     Open TCP Port:     5037
```

Comment: It would be useful to show the output of both programs and the options you used.

Comment: @LucasKauffman see update

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that you aren't seeing those open ports is because of the default behavior of nmap to only scan the 1.000 most commonly used ports.

If you want to cover all ports you need to explicitly state that you want to scan all ports with the `-p` parameter. So say I want to scan from port 1 until 5037:

```
nmap -sS 127.0.0.1 -p1-5037
```

To view which process is running on what port:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

Comment: thank you for your response ! So now, how can it be that those ports are open, how can I know which applications is using those ports ?

Comment: updated my answer, you can just lookup what process is using that particular PID

Comment: sorry when runnig your command I get `lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i 4TCP:
lsof 4.85`

Comment: did you change $port to the given port? I'll update my question

Comment: thank you ! one last question why is this command `lsof` much more rapid than `nmap` ?

Comment: nmap is used for scanning open ports on IPs, so you can use it on remote machines. lsof is actually a tool which looks in the operating system and sees what processes are using what ports.